# Lightweight HTTP streaming solution needed?

Tags: c, iframe, webserver, embedded, comet

I'm developing a web based backend to an embedded system to which we have implemented the code for the servers get requests (all built in c). I need a lightweight solution to stream an array of data values to populate a graph built using the canvas tag. Im looking at the comet pattern and potentially the iframe solution.

However Im not sure how to implement this with out a full web server running? Im fairly new to web technologies and any help or pointing me in a direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Do you have a minimum HTML revision to which you're targeting, a minimum set of web browser versions?

Comment: I am aiming at using google chrome to take advantage of some of HTML5 features, also I am using TCP protocol should have mentioned that above.

Comment: Potentially you could go with web sockets as an option. Then you can just squirt whatever you want down them...

Comment: Are you saying you have the HTTP server capability and need some client side support, or do you need the HTTP server functionality to embed in your back end?

Answer (score 2):

As [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109725/joe) suggested in a comment, have a look at web sockets. Here's a few useful links to get you started.

[Websockets 101](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/9/24/websockets-101/)

[socket.io](http://socket.io/), client and server implementation

[libwebsockets – HTML5 Websocket server library in C](http://warmcat.com/_wp/2010/11/01/libwebsockets-html5-websocket-server-library-in-c/)

[Websocket test suite](http://autobahn.ws/testsuite)

Comment: libwebsocket looks like a good solution as it's written in C and the asker is familiar with C. There's also a [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) which I'm maintaining which contains a number of other WebSocket and Comet solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm looking into websockets as we speak. Sorry for any confusion but I'm just getting to grips with the source code I've been given. It seems the server running on our system is LwIP (v1.2), does anyone know if this can handle websockets or know of any example implementation?